# Save a counter list to a file in python

Tags: python, string, list, counter

I have this and I want to save a counter list to a file:

```
def main():
    #Ask for the input filename
    nameInput = input("Enter the name of the input file: ")

    #Open the file name that was specified
    filename = open(nameInput, 'r')

    #Read the file that was specified
    textFile = filename.read()

    #Get the word count in the file
    wordCount = (textFile.split())

    #Print out the word count
    print("There are",len(wordCount),"words in this file.")

    #Import the Counter module
    from collections import Counter

    #Get the frequency of every word in the file
    freq = Counter(wordCount)

main()
```

How can I save the "freq" string to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just open another file in `w` write mode and then do writing the value of variable `freq` to that file.

```
def main():
    #Ask for the input filename
    nameInput = input("Enter the name of the input file: ")

    #Open the file name that was specified
    filename = open(nameInput, 'r')

    #Read the file that was specified
    textFile = filename.read()

    #Get the word count in the file
    wordCount = (textFile.split())

    #Print out the word count
    print("There are",len(wordCount),"words in this file.")

    #Import the Counter module
    from collections import Counter

    #Get the frequency of every word in the file
    freq = Counter(wordCount)
    with open('outfile', 'w') as w:
        w.write("The word frequency is " + str(freq))
    filename.close()

main()
```

Comment: You forgot to add the 'w'  in your  with statement.

Comment: @RandomPRSN welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).